# Creating Android App That Pronounce Every Letter of the Alphabet

Tags: java, android, android-emulator

I'm new in creating android app using eclipse. I am planning to create an app for kids that shows the alphabets and pronounce every letter. Example, when the user presses the button for the letter A the phone will pronounce the letter A How can integrate the sound with each of the letter of the alphabet? Please help.

Comment: What are you asking?  Please be more specific.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you´re asking about how to implement the Text-To-Speech, try looking [Using Text-to-Speech](http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/tts.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can put audio files into the raw folder and link them with the letters, this way, when tapping a letter a file will play with the sound. that's the only solution I can come up with.